# BadImageFormatException when trying to install msi

Tags: c#, installation, badimageformatexception, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am using VS 2015 and .net framework 4.6. I have one solution with multiple projects. When i build the solutions it works fine. I build solution and all the projects for Release x64. I have one installer project as well which contains dll of all the projects. When i build the installer it build successfully. The real problem comes when i am trying to install that build.
It gives me an exception : BadImageFormatException[image]

Comment: BadImageFormat typically occurrs when a 64bit program attempts to load a 32bit dll, or vice versa...

Comment: @CaiusJard..agreed but the machine on which i am trying to install the msi is of 64 bit.So ideally it should not give any issue.

Comment: Nevertheless a cross-architecture load attempt is the number one reason for this issue. The fact that you are on a 64-bit machine does not matter. You could still be trying to load a 32-bit assembly somewhere. Is the MSI a 64-bit TargetPlatform? You mention the code but not the MSI's build.

Comment: Also check the NET FW versions. If there is code targeted at the NET 4.0 CLR a NET 2 CLR (up to and including NET 3.x) won't load it.

Comment: @PhilDW..thanks for your help Phil. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the NET FW versions. If there is code targeted at the NET 4.0 CLR a NET 2 CLR (up to and including NET 3.x) won't load it.

(Added as an answer following poster's response).