# How to debug a service application and check which dependency is missing from application

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dependencies, installation, sharepoint-2016

[image]

I am trying to debug a service application and when I run  setup project I get the above error when installing the project. 
How do I determine which dependency is missing in visual studio??

I have no Build errors. Build is successfully.

Comment: The first place to look, is usually the definition of the Exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx#Remarks

Comment: System.BadImageFormatException tipically refers to a x86/x64 incompatibility

Comment: Thank you NicoRiff. Changing to a x86 worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a missing dependency message. There are two reasons for this:

1. A cross architecture call, 32/64 bit as NicoRiff says. Somewhjere in the calling sequence of managed code (probably a custom action) there is a cross-bitness call.
2. A NET 2.0 assembly has been loaded into the NET 4.0 runtime and won't run. That's the same issue as here:

[BadImageFormatException when trying to install msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345168/badimageformatexception-when-trying-to-install-msi)